# Adding a function to an array

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I am adding an anonymous function to an array and attempting to iterate over that array executing its contents. Even with a simple test case, I am getting a TypeError:  is not a function.

Am I missing something simple?

```
//an array of functions
var signInFunctions = [];

//add a function to the array
signInFunctions.push(function() {
    console.log("hello world");
});

function userSignedIn() {
    //execute all functions in the signInFunctions array 
    for (var i = 0; i < signInFunctions.length; i++) {
        signInFunctions(i);
    }
}

userSignedIn();
```

Here's the error:

```
TypeError: 'function () {
console.log("hello world");
}' is not a function (evaluating 'signInFunctions(i)')
```

Comment: You need `signInFunctions[i]();`

Comment: try `signInFunctions[i]();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an array of functions, so first you need to access the function at that index and *then* call it:

```
signInFunctions[i]();
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `signInFunctions(i);` use `signInFunctions [i] ();`